# Поменять местами 2 элемента списка C++

Tags: c++, list

```
Помогите пожалуйста, если можно, с комментариями, не понимаю, как менять совсем((
      #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;
        struct element
         {
                int x;
                element* Next;
         };

         class List
         {
               element* Head;
               public:
               List()
              {
                Head = NULL;
               }
              ~List();
              void Add(int x);
              void Show();
              List::~List()
               {
              while (Head != NULL)
              {
                element* temp = Head->Next;
                delete Head;
                Head = temp;
              }
              }

              void List::Add(int x)
               {
               element* temp = new element;
               temp->x = x;
               temp->Next = Head;
               Head = temp;
               }

               void List::Show()
                {
              element* temp = Head;

              while (temp != NULL)
               {
                  cout << temp->x << " ";
                  temp = temp->Next;
                }
                }

   int main()
   {

    int N;                        //Число элементов в список
    int x;                        //Элементы вводимые в список
    List lst;

    cout << "N = ";
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ". x = ";
        cin >> x;
        lst.Add(x);
    }

    lst.Show();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
Нашла вот этот код и не могу никак объединить 
SingleList *a = ptr->Next;
SingleList *b = a->Next;
ptr->Next = b; // a -> b -> c
               //      ^         
               //  ptr |

a->Next = b->Next;  //        a -> c
                    //             ^
                    //  ptr ->   b |

b->Next = a;        //  ptr -> b -> a -> c
```

Comment: отформатируйте нормально вопрос

Comment: необходимо поменять два элемента списка

Comment: Используйте кнопку править

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас однонаправленный список, т.е. элемент знает где находится следующий элемент, но не знает где находится предыдущий

чтобы поменять 2 элемента местами, надо поменять значения элементов местами (в данном случае значение переменной `x`)

Если у вас есть указатель на эти элементы, то все просто

```
element* first;
element* second;

const int tmp = second->x;
first->x = second->x;
second->x = tmp
```

Проблема только в том, что в указанном вами коде элементы списка приватные - к ним имеет доступ только класс, а снаружи до них не добраться

Поэтому самый простой вариант - добавить метод

```
void List::Swap(const int index1, const int index2) {
    // найти элемент #1
    element* element1 = Head;
    for (int index = 0; index < index1; index++)
        element1 = element1->Next;

    // найти элемент #2
    element* element2 = Head;
    for (int index = 0; index < index2; index++)
        element2 = element2->Next;

    // поменять местами значения найденных элементов
    const int tmp element2->x;
    element1->x = element2->x;
    element2->x = tmp;
}
```

P.S.

кстати раз уж вся начинка списка спрятана в приватные методы класса, то и структуру `element` тоже лучше спрятать внутрь класса и сделать приватной

Comment: Спасибо большое, но почему-то не получается((
А с помощью первого способа, мне нужно сделать   element* Head public?

Comment: @orinao, что именно не получается? какие именно элементы вы хотите поменять местами? да нет, пусть head сидит приватным, зачем его публичным делать?

Comment: в STL есть стандартный шаблонный класс std::list<T>(#include <list>) можете подглядеть как он устроен. Например, в вашем случае, объявить массив структур можно так std::list<element> element_list; все что вам нужно уже там есть, в том числе и добавление / удаление и изменение порядка элементов. Если описание класса-списка не является вашим заданием, то всегда лучше использовать код из стандартных библиотек, т.к. другим он будет понятен без ковыряния в чужих велосипедах.

Comment: Для данной задачи годится, но в общем случае такой метод не верен (не тому учите студента). Нужно менять указатели у элементов списка, а не содержимое. Представьте, что будет если на элемент, включенный в список есть указатель (или несколько указателей, полученных вообще до того, как данный элемент вставили в конкретный список) из разных структур программы.

Comment: @avp, ну так то согласен, тогда надо найти i-1, j-1, i, j, элементы для смены значений у членов Next, учесть случай, если элементов меньше 4

Comment: @Zhihar, меньше 4-х в списке не надо, а вот не первый-последний ли один из них и не соседи ли они надо

Comment: @avp я думал про циклический список, но вообще да, согласен